# How to handle theme customization and sass variables

Tags: theme-development, customization

> **TL;DR:** would you run `gulp` on a production server everytime an admin saves the theme customization settings?

Hi,

I've been using gulp+sass+WordPress for some time and now I am developing a theme in which the end user will be able to change the colors via **the customizer**.

I'm used at having a `variables.scss` with all my colors and stuff.

My first step was to seed this `variables.scss` with the customizer variables via an action on `customize_save_after`.

Of course that works as in *I have all the colors I chose on the customizer* written into my `variables.scss` and when I run `gulp` on my development machine it gets the corret values and everything is great...

Except I did not think about the production machine.

I was not planning on having gulp installed on my production machine so, with my current workflow I don't see a way to keep using sass variables for colors and fonts.

I know I can solve it getting all the afectd styles out of sass and into a regular `.css` file that would be apendend after the regular compiled `main.css` but it seems like a major step back.

I do use a lot of the sass functions (darken, lighten, transparentize…) to play with the base colors so it's not just *move everything* to a non-compiled stylesheet.

> If this was a general programming question I would be posting that on [software enginerring stack exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), not on regular *stack overflow* but I guess even if it is not a *code* problem, beeing so WordPress centric it fits better here than on softwareengineering.

Thanks!

Comment: it is actually a general web development question, and the answer in all things not wordpress is probably that you don't change anything on production, and don't have ruby or node.js installed just to be able to run gulp. All changes are first need to be tested on test server and than the change pushed to production.

Comment: Thanks @MarkKaplun but the changes are made by the end user on a CMS. That's the whole point of the thing. There is no way to test those because the developer will not even be arround to test those

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding how from PHP the SCSS file can be updated.  You mentioned "My first step was to seed this variables.scss with the customizer variables via an action on customize_save_after.".  Could you share a snippet of code of how you're getting that to communicate with the SASS file?

Comment: Hi @Erich, It's been a long time since I wrote this code and I don't have it with me. At the moment I was exploring writing the file in the filesystem with PHP.
I ended using css variables and not bothering with compiling sass https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I would. `gulp` is very light weight and I don't see any problem to keep it running in the production server and watching my `scss` files in the background.

However, if for some reason the production server is out of your control or you don't want to install extra software, you can of course use a [PHP `scss` compiler](https://leafo.github.io/scssphp/) and attach it to your theme's `functions.php` file to recompile the `scss` file to `css` for the customizer changes.

You can use the [`customize_save_after`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/customize_save_after-2/) hook to watch for the customizer changes and then execute the `scss` compiler. That way every time someone makes a change to the customizer, you'll be able to recompile the `scss` file to reflect the changes in your css file.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'll go the gulp way or the SCSS way but given that you mention both I'm happily accepting the answer. Thanks!

Comment: scssphp moved to github; here's a more current link. http://leafo.github.io/scssphp/

Answer (score 2):

I am unable to comment due to lack of points, but fear this isn't a 'complete' solution.

You could investigate this SCSSPHP library here: http://leafo.net/scssphp/

It could compile SCSS for you, without Gulp.

Comment: Thanks Doug, @Fayaz did mention PHP SCSS copmiler in his second paragraph and I did not know about that. I'll definitely check that

Comment: scssphp moved to github; here's a more current link. http://leafo.github.io/scssphp/